# Send mail to people other than contact or lead

Tags: apex

I have a requirement in which I have to write code to send mail to people who are neither contact nor lead. They are people working in our company and do not have any Salesforce login. I have created a workaround by creating contacts of them. And it is always a dangerous thing to  have them in Contact as Admin can delete them by mistake. If not now sometimes in future. So my concern is to have a solution in which I can send mail to them without any fear of loosing there contact as it is a continuous basis process. This mail does not go to our client and wholly and solely for internal purpose. Can somebody help me.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce provides functionality to send email to any person regardless of Contact or Lead or User. However it is bound with a quite restrictive Salesforce [governor limit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm):

> to a maximum of 1,000 external email addresses per day

Here is a sample code to send email to any email address:

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                  

    String subject = 'Subject Line ';
    email.setSubject(subject);

    // text
    String body = 'Information you need to send'; 

    // Set HTML body for nice foramtting
    email.setHTMLBody(body);

    // Set eamil address of person who you want to send the email. Also you can set multiple email addresses too.
    email.setToAddresses(new String[]{'name.surname@company.com'});

    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.singleEmailMessage[] {email});
```

Comment: The problem in the above solution is the hardcoded nature of email address. In my case it can change anytime(due to transfer to another department or etc.). So I have to go back to Sandbox or other means and change it. Scenario: A picklist gets updated on custom object and  a mail gets triggered to the internal employee to do a job. Sometime one value gets updated: 2 different mails to 2 different departments. Hopefully you understand my concern.

Comment: @rohit To solve this problem you need a custom object and Apex trigger with the solution above.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I am doing the same Regal. Thanks. But my problem is that I have to send different mails at different steps so different template. Then how can I send mail after fetching template ID to them. Any solution.

Comment: Template ID can only be chosen in case of lead/contact. Right? If I am wrong please correct me.